# Finding the number of cores the program uses?

Tags: linux

I had Linux cluster with RAM - 1TB

I had allocated five threads and submitted job to the cluster. 
How can I find how many cores does my program use? How much RAM does my program use? Reference to my Linux cluster specifications is below.[image]

Comment: Would you please provide more clarifications about your cluster. Is it running `Grid Engine `,`PBS/Torque,`,`, Slurm`.. ..etc? In addition, you can specify the number of cores that you would like the job to use once you submit the job.

Comment: I didn't installed any kind of scheduler in the cluster.Its just an single node cluster.

Comment: Its just an single node cluster,

Comment: Single-node cluster is a bit of a stretch but I suppose it can be done. Regardless of that, if you submitted a job to the cluster then you must have used some scheduler to submit the job. Was this `at`, `qsub`, `bsub`, `nohup`, or some other command?

Comment: I didn't installed any scheduler in linux cluster. How to calculate total number of threads in linux cluster ? i find- Total Processors - 128 (0 - 127), Each processor - 16 cores, Threads per core - 2, Total cores - 2048, Total threads - 2048 x 2 => 4096 threads in Linux cluster I calculated whether it is correct ?

Answer (score 1):

If you can login to your "node" while your threads are running, try

```
top
```

or

```
htop
```

This should give you the cores and memory your threads are currently using.

Comment: BY looking in to specifications i find- Total Processors - 128 (0 - 127)
Each processor - 16 cores
Threads per core - 2
Total cores - 2048
Total threads - 2048 x 2 => 4096 threads in Linux cluster
I calculated whether it is correct ?

Comment: I think you are mixing up some terms here. 

In computing a "cluster" usually refers to a lot of computers connected via a fast network. A computer has one or more "sockets" for "CPUs"
A "CPU" or "processor" usually consists of multiple "cores". 
One "core" can work on one program "process" at a time. If "hyperthreading" or "simultaneous multithreading" is enabled one core can work on multiple processes at once.
If a program is spitted into multiple "threads", this threads can run on multiple cores. Thus, enabling one program to run on multiple cores at once to speed up the calculation.

Comment: In your example you have a computer with four sockets. Each socket has a E7-4850V4 CPU with 16 cores. As this is a Intel CPU and Hyperthreading is activated, each core is seen by the Linux operation system as two "hyperthreaded" cores. Thus, you can usually run up to 128 threads to gain performance. However, this highly depends on your code.

The answer to your question is: You can start (with unlimited memory) an close to unlimited amount of threads. Threads are like processes just code running on CPUs. They are virtual entities controlled by the operation system describing "running" code.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I had intel with 4 sockets.Each socket has 16 cores total cores 64 cores. Each core has 2 threads 64 x 2 ==> 128 threads.